# Why is risky sport about absorbing magical creatures not banned?

Tags: magic, mythical-creatures, sports

Set during the medieval period say between 500 to 600AD, there are magical creatures inhabiting the same world as us. These magical creatures actually exist in a parallel world but an impact from an unnamed asteroid created a disturbance that rippled through our world and theirs, tearing the fabric of reality asunder, and opened a gateway bridging both worlds permanently.

(Actually, this asteroid wasn't a coincidence, but the wrath of the last old god in the universe, named "The Terribly Old One"... nevermind, back to my question).

Very often, a few magical beasts would trespass into our world through the gateway and materialise; in this state they lose their ethereal body and become mortal. People soon discovered that they can consume and absorb the magical essence of a dying magical beast and soon it becomes a trend: Whoever absorbs the magical essence from the dying magical beast can experience a brief moment of guaranteed good luck. (Note that a beast's last breath contains its magical essence.)

Each person can absorb the magical essence from one dying magical beast in their entire lifetime. The magical power bestowed upon the lucky person will manifest once only, at some random time, and lasts a few seconds. Each magical beast can sustain tons of damage before dying. They are quick and agile but do not have ranged attack. (Bad news for those people who dare cross the gateway: The number of migrating beasts isn't a coincidence either, but that's not important.)

The question is: Since the chances of encountering these magical beasts is very slim, why are people encouraged to risk their life hunting them for sport? I'm pretty sure there is some kind of policing system in place to maintain peace and safeguard lives and property, but why isn't there any rule to keep people from courting death by participating in the deadly sport?

Comment: Are you kidding? We have people in this earth who have done incredibly risky stuff for less than the guaranteed promise of few seconds of luck. There are people *today* who would risk their life or merely well-being/health without a reward promised. On a dare. I suppose the reward can be thought of as "appreciation" but it's still almost inconsequential.

Comment: Sorry about the erection of word wall, I just couldn't help it! Feel free to do formatting and fix my non-existent grammar.

Comment: @user6760 I think I've fixed your wording, but you better make sure I haven't changed something important.  Feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: @user6760 First a little nitpick. 500-600 BC wasn't the medieval period. Medieval was 400s - 1400s AD. So did you want a medieval-tech society or an ancient society? I also noticed you used the phrase "Why are people **encouraged** to risk their life..." When you say, "encouraged," how is it being encouraged? Or is it just your way of saying it's really common?

Comment: @VLAZ: American professional football, for instance.  Young men train extensively for a career which they have a small chance of attaining, but which might bring them wealth (which they typically squander) along with a very real chance of severe brain damage and other debilitating injuries.

Comment: Back then there weren't laws against doing dangerous things.  Why would it be illegal?

Comment: how good is this luck is it enough to say cure a disease?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Kings and Nobility like to have good luck at some point in their life.

In order to hunt such beasts they would gather a hunt together of men at arms and foresters  just as in the real world they hunted bears, wolves, lions, boars and other dangerous creatures.

As only the final breathe transfers the magical essence the high ranking individual need only step in to deliver the killing blow once others have critically injured the magical beast with arrows, spears, polearms etc. Just as in a bull fight only the matador kills the bull.

Answer (score 1):

**The creatures are against One True God.  Killing one is an act of devotion.**

These are weird things, these creatures.  The religious powers that be make it known that these creatures are anathema and represent the evil and ungodly.  They must be destroyed.  To track them down and kill them is to strike a blow against Power of Evil and show your devotion and dedication for One True God.  The blessing one gets for achieving this end is a reward from aforementioned One True God, from whom all blessings come.  Yah, yah, breath, all that etc but it is from One True God.

Questing after one of these creatures in order to kill it is a sort of pilgrimage or rite of fate.  Usually this is reserved for people with the wherewithal to actually pull off killing one - knights, princes and the like.  Occasionally a commoner receives a vision that he or she is to undertake such a quest, and sets off to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options I'm thinking of so I'll share them with you here.

First Option: It is illegal, but it happens anyways.

Look at our own world. There are animals that are illegal to poach. Asian markets like ivory for its supposed healing properties and so while it's illegal to poach elephants/rhinos for their ivory, it still happens. So if in a world where the benefits of ivory "medicine" have been thoroughly debunked, you still have illegal poaching of animals that could definitely kill a person if they got close enough, it would be little surprise that in a world where there is a proven benefit of a moment of luck from these animals, it would not at all be surprising if people hunted them in spite of it being illegal. ( And to acknowledge the primary reason the poachers do it is for the money, not magic ivory, you could have people paying the poachers to take them on these trips to get the last breath or other things. )

Second Option: The culture values bravery

In ancient India, hunting dangerous animals with katars was a way for a person to show bravery. ( https://www.metmuseum.org/blogs/now-at-the-met/2015/decorous-and-deadly 2nd and 3rd paragraphs ) Given that hunting something like a tiger or crocodile using an essentially glorified dagger was a rite of passage, it wouldn't be unrealistic for the hunting of dangerous animals to be a rite of passage or proving of bravery in your society. The bonus of luck makes it all the more sweeter.

Third Option: They just really want the luck

We've already established that people will pay good money for things of less benefit and that danger doesn't exactly discourage people, it wouldn't be surprising if they did it for the luck itself. A few moments of luck at the right time can definitely be valuable. And let's imagine if the kingdom had an elite army of soldiers whose luck just hadn't come yet, hoping to unleash it during a critical moment in a battle. ( "Well yes, enemy, you may have us surrounded, but you're about to get beaten by the luckiest troops you've ever seen." ) So having some luck come of the hunt is in and of itself a strong motivation for the hunt.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps absorbing a creature's magical essence brings more than just dumb *luck*. Sure, having luck is great, but only unleashed for one time? A time that may or may not be random? Plenty of people (idiot people) would try to hunt down magical creatures for luck or as a sign of bravery, but smart people would likely stay away.

It only lasts a *few seconds*, and you don't even get a guarantee that the luck will come when it's *important.* This is essentially gambling, gambling that involves deadly magical creatures. *However.....* in the book *Monstrous* and the series *The Dragon Prince*, humans don't have a magic of their own and get it from magical creatures.

You said yourself that people absorb the magical essence of the creature, so why can't they gain magic this way? Even if that magic is limited in scope, and you can only absorb magical essence from so many creatures, people will be all over that. *Everyone* will want a little bit of magic!